# Ansible wait_for connection timeout for ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

```
- hosts: "tag_deployment_group_{{ env }}_{{ app }}"
  gather_facts: false
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
 - name: "wait for instances to boot up"
   wait_for: port=22 delay=30 connect_timeout=300 search_regex=OpenSSH state=started
 - name: "copy cron script"
   hosts: "tag_deployment_group_{{ env }}_{{ app }}"
   copy: src=/etc/ansible/files/script.sh dest=/root/scripts/script.sh
```

```
<10.0.0.1> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o 
ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o 
PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-
keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=root -o 
ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/c7f4018000 -tt 
10.0.0.1> '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-
tmp-1511255180.71-122270830456576/wait_for.py; rm -rf 
"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1511255180.71-122270830456576/" > 
/dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.0.0.2> (255, '', 'ssh: connect to host 10.0.0.2 port 22: 
Connection timed out\r\n')
fatal: [10.0.0.2]: UNREACHABLE! => {
"changed": false, 
"msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 
10.0.0.2 port 22: Connection timed out\r\n", 
"unreachable": true
}
<10.0.0.1> (0, '\r\n{"elapsed": 30, "search_regex": "OpenSSH", 
"state": "started", "invocation": {"module_args": 
{"active_connection_states": ["ESTABLISHED", "FIN_WAIT1", "FIN_WAIT2", 
"SYN_RECV", "SYN_SENT", "TIME_WAIT"], "state": "started", "port": 22, 
"delay": 30, "search_regex": "OpenSSH", "host": "127.0.0.1", "sleep": 
1, "timeout": 300, "exclude_hosts": null, "msg": null, "path": null, 
"connect_timeout": 300}}, "path": null, "port": 22}\r\n', 'Shared 
connection to 10.0.0.1 closed.\r\n')
ok: [10.0.0.1] => {
"changed": false, 
"elapsed": 30, 
"failed": false, 
"invocation": {
    "module_args": {
        "active_connection_states": [
            "ESTABLISHED", 
            "FIN_WAIT1", 
            "FIN_WAIT2", 
            "SYN_RECV", 
            "SYN_SENT", 
            "TIME_WAIT"
        ], 
        "connect_timeout": 300, 
        "delay": 30, 
        "exclude_hosts": null, 
        "host": "127.0.0.1", 
        "msg": null, 
        "path": null, 
        "port": 22, 
        "search_regex": "OpenSSH", 
        "sleep": 1, 
        "state": "started", 
        "timeout": 300
    }
}, 
"path": null, 
"port": 22, 
"search_regex": "OpenSSH", 
"state": "started"
```

I am trying to launch couple of instances and perform tasks on the instances and for some reason my Ansible playbook fails in the wait_for module for one of the instances after ec2 instance launch.

I have tried different connect_timeout, but I dont think it waits for 300s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you try to execute the module on the very same machine that you wish to “wait for”. As it is unavailable, the connection required to upload and run the module fails (that’s why it doesn’t wait for the timeout specified).

Add `delegate_to: localhost`/`connection: local` or use [`wait_for_connection` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/wait_for_connection_module.html) instead.